# Autoincrementing multiple string-number values used for Serial Number on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to share the code I currently have for this:

```
const DRH = ("Davao Regional Hospital");
const SPMC = ("Southern Philippines Medical Center");
const KDH = ("Kidapawan Doctors Hospital");
const MSMH = ("Mlang Specialist Medical Hospital");
const MDHCC = ("Mindanao Doctors Hospital and Cancer Center");
const KPH = ("Kabacan Polymedic Hospital");
const DAPH = ("Dr. Aturo Pinggoy Hospital");
const SCH = ("Socsargen County Hospital");
const DDSPH = ("Davao del Sur Provincial Hospital");
const DOPMC = ("Davao Oriental Provincial Medical Center");

const davaoRH = "DVODRH-0";
const davaoSPMC = "DVOSPMC-0";
const davaoKDH = "DVOKDH-0";
const davaoMSMH = "DVOMSMH-0";
const davaoMDHCC = "DVOMDHCC-0";
const davaoKPH = "DVOKPH-0";
const davaoDAPH = "DVODAPH-0";
const davaoSCH = "DVOSCH-0";
const davaoDDSPH = "DVODDSPH-0";
const davaoDOPMC = "DVODOPMC-0";

var numberDRH = 0;
var numberSPMC = 0;
var numberKDH = 0;
var numberMSMH = 0;
var numberMDHCC = 0;
var numberKPH = 0;
var numberDAPH = 0;
var numberSCH = 0;
var numberDDSPH = 0;
var numberDOPMC = 0;


function hospitalTag(){
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Hospitals");
   var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
   var columnC = ["C"]
   var hospital = ss.getRange(columnC + lastrow);
   var triggerCancel = hospital.getValue();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
   if (triggerCancel == DRH){
     ++numberDRH
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoRH + numberDRH);
     Logger.log(numberDRH)
     } else if (triggerCancel == SPMC){
     ++numberSPMC;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoSPMC + numberSPMC);
     } else if (triggerCancel == KDH){
     ++numberKDH;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoKDH + numberKDH);
     } else if (triggerCancel == MSMH){
     ++numberMSMH;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoMSMH + numberMSMH);
     } else if (triggerCancel == MDHCC){
     ++numberMDHCC;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoMDHCC + numberMDHCC);
     } else if (triggerCancel == KPH){
     ++numberKPH;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoKPH + numberKPH);
     } else if (triggerCancel == DAPH){
     ++numberDAPH;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoDAPH + numberDAPH);  
     } else if (triggerCancel == SCH){
     ++numberSCH;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoSCH + numberSCH);
     } else if (triggerCancel == DDSPH){
     ++numberDDSPH;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoDDSPH + numberDDSPH);
     } else if (triggerCancel == DOPMC){
     ++numberDOPMC;
     ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoDOPMC + numberDOPMC);
     }
  }
}
```

I am aware that it is not at all even close to being efficient, which is why I am here.

First of all:

1. I would like to learn how to keep the value of the number incrementing per run for the ID.
2. I would like to learn a more efficient way in doing this because runtime is taking super long.

[image] [image]

This is currently the output of the code above. It classifies the code to be input depending on the input placed at Column C and uses this to call on the Serial Number for it. But it remains to DVODRH-01 all the time when I want it to be incrementing like DVODRH-01, DVODRH-02, etc.

Things to Note:

1. There are around 10 Different hospitals which is equal to 10 Codes
2. I am running it through OnFormSubmit as a Trigger set in Apps Script.

What new things can I try?

Comment: Can I ask you about the detailed logic for using `DVODRH-01` for `Davao Regional Hospital`? And, in your situation, when the number is `99`, do you want the value of `DVODRH-99`? If my understanding is correct, what result do you want when the number is more than 99?

Comment: DVODRH-01 is just a tag to indicate from what hospital the entry is from and also indicates its number in the hospital. It actually saves to another sheet that records the entry to the designated Hospital its recorded which is the reason why I would like it to go from 1 to 100 depending from the Tag. I would like the tag to actually go above 1000 if possible. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: You dont have to apologize for a thing! this is like our 3rd-4th time talking until you get it hahaha! anyway, The serial numbers under constant above are just IDs for me to identify from what hospital the entry is and what number of the entry it is. Its just like an indicator from which hospital it is and what recorded number it is from the hospital. Nothing else, while i would like DVODRH-99 to become DVODRH-100 and so on from DVODRH-999 to DVODRH-1000. Hope this helps you understand!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, I cannot still understand the logic for using `DVODRH-01` for the value of `Davao Regional Hospital`. For example, in your sample input situation, the values of `DVODRH-01` have already been existing and you want to increase the number of `01` to `02`? And also, I cannot understand when the number is more than 100, what value you want. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: I observed a few challenges on the script you have provided: The conditions for the IF statement is not a string value from the current sheet which resulted into errors (e.g DRH is not a variable nor a string) as per `if (triggerCancel == DRH)`, also the inputs on Column C contains the full name of the hospital, and not some kind of code or identifier such as DRH (if this was the intention in the first place). For now, would you be able to provide a working script wherein we can replicate the issue, and also provide a sample expected output.

Comment: yes from DVODRH-01 to DVODRH-02 and so on everytime an entry is recorded to the sheet, the row is marked with DVODRH-01 which is based on the hospital which is Davao Regional Hospital. The entry comes from a form where you can choose which hospital the client is in including his name, address, etc. When you select which hospital the Client is in from the forms, it also saves the entry there including the main response spreadsheet.

Comment: @CenturyTuna oh my bad in that part! the DRH is actually a variable. I forgot to include it in the code. apologies for this, will update it right now.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated the code. Might help you understand. I am super sorry for not including such an important part of the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that the discussion has already been advanced and an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussion and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUGGESTION:**

Instead of using the native for loop, I tried using `forEach()` instead and had to refactor the entire script. You may edit this as you like.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hospitals'); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1); 
  var values = range.getValues();

  var drhid = 1; 
  var kphid = 1; 
  var spmcid = 1;
  var kdhid = 1; 
  var msmhid = 1; 
  var mdhccid = 1;
  var daphid = 1; 
  var schid = 1; 
  var ddsphid = 1;
  var dopmcid = 1;

    values.forEach(x => {
    if(x == "Davao Regional Hospital"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVODRH-0" + drhid);
      drhid++;
      console.log(values.indexOf(x) + 1);
    } else if(x == "Kabacan Polymedic Hospital"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVOKPH-0" + kphid);
      kphid++;
    } else if(x == "Southern Philippines Medical Center"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVOSPMC-0" + spmcid);
      spmcid++;
    } else if(x == "Kidapawan Doctors Hospital"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVOKDH-0" + kdhid);
      kdhid++;
    } else if(x == "Mlang Specialist Medical Hospital"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVOMSMH-0" + msmhid);
      msmhid++;
    } else if(x == "Mindanao Doctors Hospital and Cancer Center"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVOMDHCC-0" + mdhccid);
      mdhccid++;
    } else if(x == "Dr. Aturo Pinggoy Hospital"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVODAPH-0" + daphid);
      daphid++;
    } else if(x == "Socsargen County Hospital"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVOSCH-0" + schid);
      schid++;
    } else if(x == "Davao del Sur Provincial Hospital"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVODDSPH-0" + ddsphid);
      ddsphid++;
    } else if(x == "Davao Oriental Provincial Medical Center"){
      sheet.getRange(values.indexOf(x) + 1,19).setValue("DVODOPMC-0" + dopmcid);
      dopmcid++;
     }
  });

}
```

**Screenshot of the output:**

This output contains 100 rows of data.

[image]

Execution duration:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what addressed my problem. it Addressed everything I needed + unreal runtime. Thanks man! God bless you always. I will keep this in mind and use it for similar situations I may encounter.

Comment: @Dean glad that this helped. Goodluck and happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

You could improve this code by:

1. Removing the for loop. It's not doing anything.
2. Saving `ss.getLastRow()` to a variable instead of invoking it multiple times.
3. Use a switch statement instead of a long list of `if ... else ...`

You can "keep the value of the number incrementing per run for the ID" by reading the index # from the "Control Number".

Here's an example:

```
const davaoRH = 'DVODRH-0'
const davaoSPMC = 'DVOSPMC-0'
const davaoKDH = 'DVOKDH-0'
const davaoMSMH = 'DVOMSMH-0'
const davaoMDHCC = 'DVOMDHCC-0'
const davaoKPH = 'DVOKPH-0'
const davaoDAPH = 'DVODAPH-0'
const davaoSCH = 'DVOSCH-0'
const davaoDDSPH = 'DVODDSPH-0'
const davaoDOPMC = 'DVODOPMC-0'

function hospitalTag() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hospitals')
  const lastrow = ss.getLastRow()
  const columnC = 3
  const hospital = ss.getRange(lastrow, columnC)
  const triggerCancel = hospital.getValue()

  const controlNumberColumn = 19

  let numberDRH = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberSPMC = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberKDH = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberMSMH = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberMDHCC = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberKPH = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberDAPH = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberSCH = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberDDSPH = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()
  let numberDOPMC = ss.getRange(<<PUT_ROW_NUMBER_HERE>> controlNumberColumn).getValue()


  switch (triggerCancel) {
    case davaoRH:
      ++numberDRH
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoRH + numberDRH)
      break
    case davaoSPMC:
      ++numberSPMC
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoSPMC + numberSPMC)
      break
    case davaoKDH:
      ++numberKDH
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoKDH + numberKDH)
      break
    case davaoMSMH:
      ++numberMSMH
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoMSMH + numberMSMH)
      break
    case davaoMDHCC:
      ++numberMDHCC
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoMDHCC + numberMDHCC)
      break
    case davaoKPH:
      ++numberKPH
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoKPH + numberKPH)
      break
    case davaoDAPH:
      ++numberDAPH
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoDAPH + numberDAPH)
      break
    case davaoSCH:
      ++numberSCH
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoSCH + numberSCH)
      break
    case davaoDDSPH:
      ++numberDDSPH
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoDDSPH + numberDDSPH)
      break
    case davaoDOPMC:
      ++numberDOPMC
      ss.getRange(lastrow, 19, 1, 1).setValue(davaoDOPMC + numberDOPMC)
    default: return
  }
}
```

Comment: First time seeing switch/case method and I have to admit it has its uses! way better for processing time I would agree. Though I have a question, why is it that number DRH, etc. is now using getRange and getValue? how is this going to work as an Index for per case? also I do not understand this part as  i dont see anything related to it in the code "You can "keep the value of the number incrementing per run for the ID" by reading the index # from the "Control Number"." I am so sorry if I didn't get it though it answered my number one question which is faster runtime. Thanks for the input!

Comment: and how is it gonna link itself to the argument from the name of the hospital located at Column C when the hospital names are not in use in the code.

Comment: I am asking to further familiarize and improve myself in coding as well as to increase the options I can use in different situations. Thank you for the extra information!